# Overlapping records in data-warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

I'm trying to build a data-warehouse and the data is provided by three different sources. The problem here is that there are overlapping customers as the same customer can be present in all data sources but with a different identification (different primary key). How can I avoid getting the same customer more than once in my data-warehouse?

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow :) Please add some code if you have it.

Comment: Well.... you need some way to tell the computer that customer #5523 = customer # 2234. Could it be name? or address? There is a large industry of vendors who focus on identifying "unique" customers (and charge you a lot of cash to do it). This is a *business* problem, not a technical one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a business problem, not a technical one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a programming question, however the short answer is that you will need to find some method of comparing the customer records, identifying which ones are the same customer and then merging the details into a single customer record. If there is no code or other value that relates these records in different systems then, depending on the amount of records you have, your options range from having them manually compared and recording any matches, to using software for "fuzzy matching" comparisons on properties like name and address to try and find matches. You might attempt to do this in your data warehouse loading process, write an application internally to manage it or obtain a third party tool that has this capability. This is a common business problem, but unfortunately not one that has a simple solution.